# “Parrus” versus “Paris”

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, british-english

I am reading Agatha Christie's *Murder on the Orient Express* and I noticed that at least two American characters say “Parrus” to mean “Paris”.

I guess that by this Christie hints at some difference in the pronunciation of the name of Paris in (the in-universe, as described by Christie) AmE vs BrE. Is that so? Which are the two different pronunciations?

EDIT: Kenyon and Knott's 1949 *A Pronouncing Dictionary of American English* doesn't seem to be useful, since it gives the more or less [standard pronunciation /ˈpærɪs/](https://archive.org/stream/pronouncingdicti00unse#page/316/mode/2up), which is apparently the same as British one.

Comment: In AmE it's Parrus. And I hate to break it to you, but it's ver-SALES, Illinois and KAY-ro, Illinois.

Comment: @deadrat Just goes to show you should never trust an Illinoian with the faculty of speech. ;-)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet At least most of them don't pronounce the final 's' in their state's name.

Comment: Perhaps AC assumed that "Paris" was pronounced "parEE".  So to show the dialect that did not do it that way, she wrote "Parrus".

Comment: As GEdgar suggests, It seems likely to me that the difference was between "parrus" and "paree".  On the Orient Express many would pronounce it "paree", even the English.

Comment: @deadrat, I resemble that remark! ;-)

Comment: Agatha Christie is just taking the piss, as Brits say. It's only one of the characters. The character is Mrs. Hubbard and the same page is full of Paris, too. So, it's just to be funny. You can read the page here: https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/ahughes/pdfs/books/motoe.pdf I'm American and I don't say it like that. I say Paris, as in tryst.

Comment: @Lambie: I don't know, nor am interested in, the intentions of Ms Christie; I am just asking a linguistic question. And Hardman, the other American character, uses “Parrus” too (p. 74 of the .pdf you are linking).

Comment: She is suggesting that some Americans (like the crude ones on that train) would say Parrus like walrus but not all do. It's basically a class thing. /'pærɪs/ versus /'pærʌs/ is probably marked as "uneducated, middle western". If you are not interested in her intentions, how can one possibly explain it? It's her fantasy after all....not an across-the-board pronunciation in AmE by any means.

Comment: One *might* be able to listen to the movie and determine at least how the movie's producers interpreted it, perhaps with consultation with Ms Christie, perhaps not.

Comment: I see your point, @Lambie, thanks. What I meant is that, independently of Christie's intentions, I'd like to understand what she meant by “Parrus”, and in contrast with what. Just a sort of “Christie's spelling - IPA” translation, so to say.

Comment: @DaG Well, OK, but I explained it. She is saying Parrus like walrus, as opposed to Paris like ferris (wheel). I already gave the IPA somewhere around here. :)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth and the other editors: I have added a bit of research, but in addition to this, I really don't now where to look for a reference for Christie English or, better, varieties-of-English-in-Christie's-opinion English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to be sure from the spelling alone, but I think that this represents a phenomenon called the [weak vowel merger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_high_front_vowels#Weak_vowel_merger):

> The weak vowel merger is the loss of contrast between /ə/ (schwa) and unstressed /ɪ/ [...]
>
> [...]
>
> The merger is also commonly found in General American. [...]

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, is it more or less /ˈpærɪs/ in BrE and /ˈpærəs/ in AmE?

Comment: @dag Not always. Some speakers have this merger and some don't. What's more, most AmE speakers also have the Mary-marry-merry merger (57% according to Wikipedia), meaning that you're more likely to find /ˈpɛrəs/ ~ /ˈpɛrɪs/. To top it off, I've also heard some Americans trying to imitate the French pronunciation with /pəˈri/ or /pɑˈri/.

Comment: @DaG No, that is incorrect. It is the writer's interpretation of what she BELIEVES to be AmE pronunciation. I am American, I speak French and have been around a lot of Americans talking about Paris. None of them say Parrus (walrus). Perhaps it's best here for those of us who are actually Americans to say something about this. If I hear Parrus, I think: uneducated or middle American states or just not very bright.

Comment: Here too, @Lambie, please consider my comment here amended as: «So, if I understand correctly, is it more or less /ˈpærɪs/ in default assumed pronunciation by British MotOE characters and /ˈpærəs/ in pronunciation by American MotOE characters?».

Comment: I have already answered the question. Like I said, some people may say that, but not everyone. If no one said it, it would be impossible to make fun of it. I'm just saying it is not a valid marker across the board for types of speakers (speech) in AmE.

Comment: Lambie is right, but I would make a stronger statement -- Christie is caricaturing an American accent.